# Comment threads that make no sense

Tags: support, comments

I am fairly new to SE and ELU(less than a month old). While going through some questions and answers, I spotted a few comments that made absolutely no sense to me. 
Comments that appear to at-mention some user and suggest a clarification or express an opinion or simply post another question.

I guess those comments were posted *after* a series of other comments, but for some reason , all those previous comments were deleted by their respective authors.

Thus , my questions:

1. If comments add no reputation to an user and are simply there to add value to a post, then why delete them at all? Won't new users (like yours truly) find it hard to decipher the flow of comments and understand what was being discussed?
2. Is it not possible to delete all the reply comments that were triggered by a deleted source comment?

Call me a fool, but I personally feel that comments too add immense value to Q&As and I feel helpless when I see random comments without being able to understand the context.

P.S: This is my first meta-post . Please feel free to close this question if it doesn't belong here or if it is a duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Meta! You may find an answer at [Disappearing comment trails](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/disappearing-comment-trails).